# how to pass date parameters in crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I have the following script that creates a log file with current date in log file name:

```sh
#script name: abc.sh
curr_date=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`
/user/scripts/abc.sh > /user/logs/test_$curr_date.log
```

I tried to configure crontab to call `abc.sh` everyday like as below:

```
16 14 * * * /user/scripts/abc.sh || mail -s "Errors" abcd@gmail.com < /user/logs/test_$curr_date.log
```

However, crontab is unable to execute the above job, because it does not recognize `$curr_date`

How do I pass the `$curr_date` to the script when using crontab ?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please edit it to properly format code as code. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: probably all you need is `export curr_date=...` . Good luck.

Comment: It looks like you're in an infinite recursive loop: crontab calls abc.sh and abc.sh calls abc.sh -- what's up?

Answer (score 0):

In the shell this defines a variable that's local to the shell's instance:

```
curr_date=`...`
```

If you want that to apply to sub-processes:

```
export curr_date=`...`
```

Then that shows up as not only `$curr_date`, but in the env of whatever program(s) it executes.